# select array element PostgreSQL

Tags: java, sql, arrays, postgresql, jdbc

I have a column in my database called: `"CIElabOne"` which is of the type `numeric []  ("CIElabOne" numeric[])` and thus contains values like: `{9.766934377517181,0.0011685082518947398,-0.0023119569625251746}`

I cant access the values independently, when executing the following SQL query:

```
SELECT "fileName" FROM "clothItems" WHERE "CIElabOne[1]" = '9.766934377517181'
```

The result is : `ERROR: column "CIElabOne[1]" does not exist`

Selecting CIElabOne as a whole is not a problem but I need to evaluate each of the elements of the array. I don't know why this happens I am following the guide http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html but I don't seem to find the error

This is my real sql query in java:

```
sqlTwo = "SELECT \"fileName\" FROM \"clothItems\" WHERE \"CIElabOne[1]\" = '"
                    + inputColorOneCIELAB[0]
                    + "' AND \"CIElabOne[2]\" = '"
                    + inputColorOneCIELAB[1]
                    + "' AND \"CIElabOne[3]\" = '"
                    + inputColorOneCIELAB[2]
                    + "' and \"gender\" = '"
                    + inputGender
                    + "' AND \"shape\" <> '"
                    + inputShape
                    + "'";
```

inputColorOneCIELAB[] is an array of doubles

Comment: Could you please show your real Java code? It's unclear what your query really is with all these useless quotes.

Comment: Why do you quote every column name and value? Just use `select filename from clothitems where cielabone[1] = ? and ...`. Use a prepared statement and pass parameters instead of using concatenation.

Comment: I dont think quoting is a problem, I have 5 other sql queries with the cuoting and work perfectly

Comment: So, it **was** a quoting problem after all...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array subscript operator must be *outside* the quoted identifier name, otherwise it's treated as part of the identifier.

```
"CIElabOne[1]"
```

means "the column named `CIElabOne[1]`." You want:

```
"CIElabOne"[1]
```

which means "the first array element of the column `CIElabOne`.

Comment: @user3540466 Another good reason why quoted identifiers should be avoided